# Why can't I see a dll file that I copied and pasted using a copy command on Azure Dev ops repository?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, msbuild, azure-devops

I have my C# .net code deployed on Azure dev ops. There is a csproj file which has a copy command in the post build event.

```
<PropertyGroup>
<PostBuildEvent>copy /y "d:\a\1\s\C#\Ignify.Online\Organization\bin\Release\Ignify.Online.Organization.dll" "d:\a\1\s\CommerceSuiteObjects"</PostBuildEvent>
```

This command tries to copy the dll for the solution and paste it inside another folder 'CommerceSuiteObjects' which is inside the same repository. When I run the build for the solution using a pipeline, the copy command is shown to have run successfully, the build is successful as well, but I don't see the copied dll in the target folder. I am not sure if this command actually works on azure dev ops or not. Please suggest what might be wrong ?

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT, I found out that the dlls were being copied, but they were not visible in the repository probably because of gitignore, after the completion of the build I saw that the dlls were present in the artifacts.

Comment: Glad to know you have found the reason for this issue, would you mind share your comment as answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issues and find the answer easier. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Why can't I see a dll file that I copied and pasted using a copy command on Azure Dev ops repository?

First, you could double check if the `.dll` file is copied from the build task log, if yes, you will see such log:

> copy /y "D:\a\1\s\TestSample\TestSample\bin\Debug\TestSample.dll"
>   "d:\a\1\s\CommerceSuiteObjects\TestSample.dll"
>
> **1 file(s) copied**.

Second, check if you have check the correct folder when you use copy task, as test, I set the Source Folder is `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\CommerceSuiteObjects` in the copy task:

[image]

Third, the important is if you do not create that folder `CommerceSuiteObjects` in the pipeline, when you use copy event, that folder be treated as a file, to resolve this issue, I have add a command line task to create that folder before Visual studio build task:

```
if not exist CommerceSuiteObjects mkdir CommerceSuiteObjects
```

[image]

Now, it works fine on my side, I could see the `.dll` file in the `CommerceSuiteObjects` folder.

Hope this helps.